# Ошибка "файл уже используется"

Tags: java, apache-poi

Почему при записи `FileWriter` документ Word не открывается, а при записи `FileOutputStream` открывается?

Помогите, пожалуйста, нужен именно `FileWriter`.

```
Path link = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\BBB.docx");

XWPFDocument docxModel = new XWPFDocument();
if (Files.exists(link)) {
    docxModel.createParagraph();
    String documentLine = docxModel.getDocument().toString();
    CTSectPr ctSectPr = docxModel.getDocument().getBody().addNewSectPr();
    XWPFParagraph bodyParagraph = docxModel.createParagraph();
    bodyParagraph.setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.LEFT);
    XWPFRun paragraphConfig = bodyParagraph.createRun();
    XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
    XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
    paragraphConfig.setItalic(true);
    paragraphConfig.setFontSize(20);
    paragraphConfig.setColor("170101");
    paragraphConfig.setFontSize(12);
    paragraphConfig.setText(numberandnames.toString());
    try {
        document.write(new FileOutputStream(new File("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\BBB.docx")));
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
```

[image: FileWriter]

```
try {
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Admin\\Desktop\\BBB.docx");
    docxModel.write(outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new RuntimeException(ex);
}
```

[image: FileOutputStream]

Comment: Не увидел FileWriter в вашем коде.

Comment: @Vadik имел ввиду не создавая объект outputstream - не удается запустить документ. И еще проблема в постоянном очищении документа при новом запуске. Не знаете, как можно сохранить текст при следующем запуске?

Comment: В первом примере кода `document` это пустой документ, вы записываете в файл пустой документ. Во втором примере кода вы записываете `docxModel`, он не пустой. Не совсем понятен ваш вопрос, вы пишете, что используете [FileWriter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html), но в коде этого фрагмента нет. Пожалуйста, [поправьте](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1450536/edit) ваш вопрос так, чтобы было понятно.

Comment: Ошибка "файл уже используется" может происходить из-за того, что вы неправильно освобождаете ресурсы. Не закрываете документ или стрим в конце работы программы.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы освободить документ после работы программы, используйте метод [`close()`](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/ooxml/POIXMLDocument.html#close--) у документа:

```java
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
// работа с документом
document.close();
```

Но если случится ошибка в программе, то документ все равно может остаться открытым, поэтому лучше использовать конструкцию [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html):

```java
try (XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument()) {
    // работа с документом
}
```

Comment: Проблема не решена(
Я бы использовал outputstream, но не сохраняются данные в документы при следующем запуске программы